# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am creating a new table in Oracle DB using java jdbc and ending up in missing or invalid option. Dont know what is wrong in the query as such

I have tried running the same query in SQL Plus and SQL Developer and it just works fine but when run through java jdbc its throwing the above error. This is the same extract from java code as well. Using executeUpdate() method for this.

```
CREATE TABLE EventTable (
    "EVENTID" NUMBER, "MODULE" NVARCHAR2(512),"EVENTTYPE" NVARCHAR2(512),
    "MODULEANDEVENTTEXT" NVARCHAR2(512), "TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), "SOURCE" NVARCHAR2(512),
    "SEVERITY" NVARCHAR2(512), "NODE" NVARCHAR2(512), "ACKNOWLEDGED" NUMBER(*,0),
    "USERSID" NVARCHAR2(512), "DID" NVARCHAR2(512), "MID" NVARCHAR2(512), "FH" NVARCHAR2(512),
    "LD" NVARCHAR2(512), "TD" NVARCHAR2(512), "ED" NVARCHAR2(512), "UD" NVARCHAR2(512), 
    "GD" NVARCHAR2(512), PRIMARY KEY ("EVENTID")
);
```

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
```

Java Snippet

```
 countQuery.append(
                "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE EventTable ( \"EVENTID\" NUMBER,  \"MODULE\" NVARCHAR2(512),\"EVENTTYPE\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"MODULEANDEVENTTEXT\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"TIME\" TIMESTAMP , \"SOURCE\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"SEVERITY\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"NODE\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"ACKNOWLEDGED\" NUMBER(*,0), \"USERSID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"DESKTOPID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"MACHINEID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"FOLDERPATH\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"LUNID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"THINAPPID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"ENDPOINTID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"USERDISKPATHID\" NVARCHAR2(512), \"GROUPID\" NVARCHAR2(512), PRIMARY KEY (\"EVENTID\")); "); 

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(countQuery);

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you share the exact Java code that you have written?

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.tekstream.com/oracle-error-messages/ora-00922-error-message/), the problem might be the length constraint you are trying to set here: `"TIME" TIMESTAMP (6)` due to *Specifying a maximum length on a DATE or LONG datatype also causes this error.*.

Comment: Updated with code snippet.

Comment: @deHaar I tried removing the length in timestamp still the same error

Comment: @punitjashra then it might be the missing `NULL` or `NOT NULL` for each column. See [this](http://www.sqlinfo.net/oracle/oracle_Create_table.php). Even the missing `CONSTRAINT PK_EVENT` could be an issue, you have to try those options in order to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I have correct this issue on my side by removing the trailing semi-colon (;) at the end of the DML. Oracle didn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

you will need to use `Statement` object and create instance of it to execute "create `global temporary` table" query 
[`createStatment` instead of `prepareStatment`

**Reason :**

`global temporary` is not valid DDL to run from connection.PreparedStatment()

**Fix:**

```java
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(countQuery)
```